# Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast

Tags: discussion, reputation, article, strategy

From "6 Simple Tips to Get Stackoverflow Reputation Fast" at codexon.com:

1. Be the **First** to Answer. Even at the cost of quality.
2. Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically
3. Use obnoxious *in-your-face* formatting and lists.
4. Be Aware of the 200 rep/day Limit
5. Edit, But Don’t Edit Too Much
6. Associate your other accounts

Courtesy of [our pal codexon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/57757/unknown). Agree? Disagree? Walnuts? Cantaloupe?

Comment: How in the world do you downvote **strategically**...?

Comment: By downvoting other answerers who are competing with your answer. If you do that when you would not have done (had you not answered the question), then that is strategic.

Comment: More importantly, down voting answers costs you rep. So using too frequently isn't going to help your score.

Comment: @michael bounties and accepted answers are immune, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation and read it closely

Comment: Where is the part about using jQuery for the answer?!

Comment: You could always just ask a ridiculous number of questions... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1326/please-charge-rep-for-questions-after-threshold

Comment: I'm kind of appalled at the existence of this post...

Comment: What is the best strategies for downvotes?

Comment: downvoting only for the sake of for personal rep gain. Now that is anti-community.

Comment: Search for the questions or answers written by users with poor english skills and edit them (if you have privilege, of course). It gives only 2 rep, but you need patience.

Comment: ALSO Dont Comment on a post which is voted down I mean under 0, It will make them think that you were the downvoter .....

Comment: What about: Provide copy and paste solutions to simple, everyday problems in enterprise languages, especially Java [and now Swift]?

Comment: And this is how people collect votes.

Comment: Can someone please explain #6? Is that the same as merging 2 accounts created inadvertently? It seems like that would rarely happen. If it did, there wouldn't be many points in one of the accounts.

Comment: I **would** down-vote this, but I don`t have enough _reputation_

A far more constructive answer is provided [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/288077)

Comment: How does linking other accounts help?

Comment: @jorfus `If you are an experienced Stack Exchange network user with 200 or more reputation on at least one site, you will receive a starting +100 reputation bonus to get you past basic new user restrictions. This will happen automatically on all current Stack Exchange sites where you have an account, and on any other Stack Exchange sites at the time you log in.`. [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: @NeluMalancea please read my comment above. I think point#6 means association bonus. You may like to read [What is the association bonus?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus)

Comment: @Phil H "downvoting other answerers who are competing with your answer" is very evil

Comment: this have been been posted 6 years ago, but I find disgusting and unethic to "downvote" perfectly valid answers just to get reputation.

Comment: This is a very machiavellist way of thinking. Reputation is an award of giving a good answer, and that's all. A lot of people giving answers do that for self-development by helping others I believe.

Comment: These tips are not to be taken seriously, as they are clearly tongue-in-cheek. This is a satirical commentary from someone who is clearly unhappy with the status-quo.

Comment: As a long-time StackOverflow user, I **strongly disagree** with #1. The whole appeal of StackOverflow is quality answers, not fast answers at the cost of quality! It's actually upsetting to see that as a suggestion at all...

Comment: @UltraDEVV Better option is to downvote and then comment, "I did not downvote but ..."

Answer (score 1233, accepted):

I don't know about you but here's my strategy.

1. **Post high quality answers.** This should be numbered 1 2 and 3. But a good answer will more often than not trump a fast answer. Though there are cases where it does not.
2. **Monitor the [frontpage](https://stackoverflow.com/) and the [new questions list.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions)** Learn their cache time and refresh accordingly or use the tag pages ([Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23+or+java?sort=newest)) to get live updates on new questions.
3. **Set up a good but short list of Interesting and Ignored tags.** For example I have [css](/questions/tagged/css), [html](/questions/tagged/html), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) and [php](/questions/tagged/php) as interesting tags. This will help you see questions, which you can answer, quicker.
4. **Avoid Wall-of-Text questions.** They take way too much effort for little reward. And usually are syntax errors or bad structure.
5. **Post an answer even if the question already has 1–2 or even 3 answers.** In these cases, take your time and answer well. This will usually net you a good sum of rep.
6. **Learn when to edit.** Post a short answer at first and then edit. You have <5 minutes to make that answer shine.
7. **Be humble, thorough and fair.** There are a lot of smart people out there and many will know much more than you about the subject. Be thorough in the code you post, check it for syntax errors and make sure it fits the question. And if you see that the correct answer is already there, upvote it, that person deserves the rep.

Comment: I think the list should have one more item:  
8. **Provide a good and simple code example (and format it correctly)**

Comment: Now you can edit your questions and answers any time.

Comment: 9. **Demo Link**. Add link to a ready to run demo of your code. (http://codepad.org/, http://jsfiddle.net/, ...)

Comment: I would add **#8 Go Niche**.  Find something you are good at that is not as popular as **`[java]`** or **`[sql]`**.  Watch that tag every day and answer questions if you can.  There are usually fewer people on the tag and you can take more time to answer.

Comment: Regarding demo links, I totally agree. However, please keep in mind that sometimes those links get broken. That is why I consider good practice to paste that code in your answer here at SO too.

Comment: What's a "Wall of Text" question? Very verbose? Or something else?

Comment: Wall of text are unformatted big chunks of code, with little to no explanation of what is going on and what the point of the OP is.

Also check urban dictionary http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wall%20of%20text

Comment: I would like to add some points to your **point 5**. As you say `Post an answer even though the question has 1–2 or even 3 answers`, In that case check whether already existing answer have covered all the things.Sometimes more knowledge peoples will post quickly with all the thing need to be know about that point. So in that case dont try to Duplicate it.

Comment: @JeffAtwood I checked _the source_, they are clearly **strong**.

Comment: "*Post a short answer at first and then edit. You have <5 minutes to make that answer shine*" This might have been fine 5-6 years ago with a lot less users, now it doesn't help you, or anyone else. You just get downvoted immediately for posting a poor or less than useful answer.

Comment: @Jess, that doesn't work however if the askers are not reactive and/or there are few people upvoting. That's why IMHO a [gold badge for revival/necromancer pattern](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/254753/248268) is needed.

Comment: I would like to add "share the love" to the list. If you up-vote someone who is helpful they'll feel more inclined to up-vote others who are helpful in due course. How often do you visit a useful post and then not hit the up-vote? Speaking of which...

Answer (score 294):

To be perfectly honest, I absolutely agree with #3. A bit of formatting

- Makes the post more readable
- proves that the user put a bit of effort into it
- prevents the "Wall of Text crits you" effect
- stands out
- allows me to spot important points more easily
- puts some structure into the posting

And #6 is also a no-brainer. Not because of the reputation but because that gives clickable names when migrating the question.

Point #1 is well discussed, just search for the fastest gun in the west problem. And Point #5 benefits the person who asks the question, because more visibility = more chance for an answer without having to post a bounty.

So only **Point #2 is purely evil** and should be somehow monitored and actively counterattacked, but I think that's what Jeff & Co. have been doing since almost Day 1.

But **overall, I agree with these points**, because nicely formatted answers from people with accounts who bump the question once in a while to give it more exposure are a Win for the site.

To further prove my point, here is a picture of a bunny with a pancake on its head:

[image: This is Chewbacca. Chewbacca is a Wookie who lives on Endor.]

Comment: "To further prove my point, here is a picture of a bunny with a pancake on its head." That's hallarois!

Comment: I mis-read that as "a pancake with a bunny on its head".

Comment: Interesting technique to draw attention

Comment: Looks like two pancakes even.

Answer (score 143):

Is it just me, or would following these tips make you feel dirty too? Is this where the word "rep whore" comes from? Especially

**#2** - is highly unfair, gaming the system, and preventing its usefulness.
**#1** - is true, it is the old "fastest gun in the west" problem. After the first upvote(s) I can still invest in a great answer (otherwise being pushed down and I lose my first place).
**#4-6** - are great.

Am I an idealist? I would like to help and be helped. And still I find myself going after those 12 points to get edit powers at the time of writing. But at what expense? Never gonna do #2!

Comment: And I wasn't even first to answer ;-) And you noticed: no formating, no stratigical downvoting (I assure), didn't edit the answer so far. But also did not hit the 200 rep/day limit :(

Comment: "highly unfair"? It's mildly manipulative *at best*. Face it, at best you're only going to affect the ranking significantly if you and someone else posted almost-identical answers and *neither one of you edits*. I have answers posted late, with few votes for the first day and several down-votes *that are still collecting up-votes months later*, long after other, formerly high-ranked answers stalled out. IMHO, if you're in it for the game, then accept that you'll be gamed; if you're in it for the answers, then a few bogus votes make no difference.

Comment: I look at it as highly unfair in the light that the person is willing to "harm"somebody else in something that is so important to himself. I personally could care less.

Comment: To quote a [different meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote), "it [the reputation system] really is just a 'necessary evil' to aid the privilege system (and it also is a sort of reward)." Downvoting an answer just to get more rep is gaming the system, but no system is perfect, and SE's community moderated reputation system works much better than countless other forums. I hate that things like "strategic downvoting" exist on this forum, but it happens. Another good quote "Don't use it [reputation] to gauge post quality." True dat!

Answer (score 132):

Well, I certainly credit all *my* success on Stack Overflow to

1. judicious
2. use
3. of
4. obnoxious
5. lists...

Comment: I fixed your post for you

Comment: This highlights #3: Jeff, your formatting just earned Shog9 an upvote!

Comment: Also highlights #5! Though not really in the way it was intended...

Comment: This `answer` needs more `backticks` in order to be `useful` as an `answer` to the `question`.

Comment: Oh, is that where the o in `<ol>` stands for? Obnoxious list...

Comment: lol @JustusRomijn I know nothing about code, but it's probably **Ordered** list. Unless that was a joke...

Answer (score 74):

I'd add one more: *answer the questions people can understand*.

A question like "I'm having a problem with really really really tricky `SQL` query: I need to count records groupwise" will bring you `10` upvotes in a minute, if you were first to answer.

But one of the answers I'm most proud of took me something like `30` minutes and was accepted with a *negative* score (someone might have been using downvoting strategically, you know). There are just too many lines to be interesting.

Comment: My highest-scoring answer on SO was a one-liner straight from the docs..

Comment: Very true. Some of the most basic C#/Java questions are among those where the most rep is dealt out.

Comment: In specific problems are going to gainer less votes/views then a general question. Its just the nature of the beast.

Comment: So true. My highest scoring answers are quick-fire copies from the docs. BTW as we're rep farming here, why not link to your poor, unloved, masterwork? I bet it'd get upvotes (I would)

Comment: OK, my mate Google found it and I just have upvoted it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165878/optimizing-order-by-query-on-large-table-mysql/1165965#1165965

Comment: Agreed! The answer that got me the most rep was pointing out that someone used '=' instead of '=='...

Comment: @JamesMcMahon: This is not necessary a case of specific question. "Why my Java homework doesn't work" can accumulate more point the answer to "How to get code coverage in C++" despite the latter being both harder and non-specific.

Comment: This is an 1-lined answer with __bold__ _and italic_ and I won't earn any reputation from this.

Comment: @JohnFouhy, They should deal out rep not just based on upvotes, but on upvotes per view. In other words questions with more views would gain less rep per upvote.

Comment: This is so true.  I had someone say as much on a highly highly technical, very lengthy answer of mine.  Really good answers can sometimes get overlooked, and the quickly upvoted answers aren't necessarily that great, because [*"information can't be that useful if so many people already know it."*](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247209/how-to-use-cgroups-to-limit-all-processes-except-whitelist-to-a-single-cpu#comment436378_252825)

Answer (score 64):

I am formatting my answer as a list, but I have a good reason (see number 3 below):

1. **Be the first to answer**
   While the *fastest gun* problem is not new to us, the post was written for an audience not familiar with Stack Overflow, so the [OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms) is right in bringing it up. Being the first to answer is likely to bring you more votes. However, I disagree with his statement that there are many bad/wrong answers on top  of the list because of it, my own experience is that quality floats to the top.
2. **Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically**
   I don't know, most of the time I can easily see the three top answers on my screen. If a user can read them without scrolling, he/she will be very likely to do so, therefore I don't think this has a big effect. Besides, the vote difference between the first three answers is often more than two votes, so this is likely not to work at all.
   The systematic downvoting of a specific user's answers, as shown in the screenshot, will definitely be caught by the system.
3. **Use obnoxious in-your-face formatting and lists**
   There is a reason why answers with formatting are getting upvoted more often. It is the same reason why the option to use formatting exists: *Formatted answers are good answers*. The same answer in plain text is not as readable as if it was well formatted, hence the trend for answers with lists and other formatting to float to the top.
   As for answers that start with a bold **Yes** or **No** at the top: If the question asks *Is X a good thing to do?* first giving a clear answer and then elaborating on your reasons is a good practice. These answers are upvoted because they are good answers.
4. **Be Aware of the 200 reputation/day Limit**
   The reputation limit was never a problem for me, because I never got near ;-)
5. **Edit, But Don’t Edit Too Much**
   Editing in order to bump up the question on the home page is a strategy that is likely to work. Unfortunately.
6. **Associate your other accounts**
   Hey, I did that! And you know what: I got 100 points out of it!!!!!
   **Once.** Not such a big deal, really.

At the end I am left wondering: Most of us got to a point when we didn't consider our reputation that important any more. For me that was after I passed the 3k threshold on Stack Overflow and was allowed to vote on closing questions. (Yes, most of the people who tell others not worry about their reputation so much, because *hey, it ain't that important, you know*,  have a reputation where it really isn't that important any more.)
Somehow, the OP doesn't seem to fall into that category.

Comment: This answer sucks, it has no picture in it.

Comment: I was with you till point 5. Refining and bumping is not only a strategy, it is highly encouraged! For point 6 you get my favourite punctuation mark link: http://sockenseite.de/__oneclick_uploads/2006/10/ausruf.html

Comment: +1 specifically for the point you make in the end: "Most of us got to a point when we didn't consider our rep that important any more." After I was able to retag questions & edit CW posts on SO I was happy with the privileges, and have had no compulsive need to try to accumulate more rep. (Although getting past 2k did make the copy editor in me even happier, and of course upping the rep score always gives you *some* warm buzz... :-)

Comment: @John Smithers: Quoting from the linked page: *Die Wichtigkeit eines Newspostings im Usenet ist reziprok zur Anzahl der 
enthaltenenen, kumulierten Ausrufungszeichen.* Which is exactly the point I was trying to make ;-)

Comment: @Treb: It still hurt my eyes. And it drags down the whole post.

Comment: Well, reputation is somewhat important in the begining, especially in cases when you cannot up-vote other people's answers, just because there is limit of let's say 15 reputation to do that.

Answer (score 55):

#2 on this list "Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically" makes me rage.

I prefer Jon Skeet's advice on [Answering technical questions helpfully](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully/).

Comment: Seeing as he has 229k reputation **as of this writing**, I would take his advice :-)

Comment: +1 Agree - not only is Jon Skeet a SO living legend, he's polite & funny.

Comment: @AndréCaron And now, seven years later, he's at... Only 940k?! He's been slacking!

Answer (score 42):

### Ways to amass rep that *positively* impact the site.

There are plenty of vampiric strategies that one can employ. Those that overall don't make the site a better place to be. That don't make it a more effective place to get questions answered. I'll be talking about the ways that make the site work *better*.

I find that there are two general strategies to getting rep quickly:

#### Frequently visit "high-churn" tags

These are tags that get a *lot* of questions. Which means they quickly get a lot of answers. But the former means that, if you visit the site 20 times a day, odds are you will find a few questions that you can answer which have not yet been answered.

Naturally, this requires some significant expertise in high-churn fields, so that you can not simply quickly answer questions, but do so effectively. You can expect to get 2-4 upvotes on these questions, so you don't need more than 4-6 of them daily before you hit the cap. And it doesn't even matter if a couple of others slip in; as long as you're within the first 4 minutes of the question hitting the site, you stand a good chance of getting some upvotes.

Well, assuming your answer is *correct*.

#### Have significant expertise in a "low-churn" tag

Maybe this tag only gets 10 questions a day. Maybe only 4 regular contributors even check the tag, let alone know how to answer them.

Being able to serve the under-served parts of SO means that you don't have to visit very often, but it also means you get a lot more *accepts*, rather than just upvotes. So if you combine these two strategies, the 200 rep barrier becomes less important, since accepted answer rep doesn't count against it.

Indeed, if you happen to have a lot of various obscure knowledge, serving the under-served parts of SO can get you all the rep you need. Plus, you get to help people who might otherwise have not gotten help.

The downside here is that the low-churn tags are also more likely (by volume) to be from new posters who don't know what the accept button is, or don't even have the rep to upvote. However, those few regular contributors to those tags will likely hit you with an upvote when they see your answer.

---

*Other Tactics*

There are also other tactics that you can employ in your answer. One that I do as a matter of course that just so happens to fit in is to add useful advice while answering. You should know the general idioms around a particular knowledge base and preach them where possible.

For example, if you're answering a C++ question where someone is gratuitously using `new`, add a suggestion to your answer that they use a stack variable. If they're talking about writing destructors, bring up the Rule of Three and smart pointers. Experienced C++ programmers will almost always upvote you for that, and you'll be helping someone find programming techniques that they may not have found otherwise.

Overkill is another tactic. If you can't be first, then by God be *biggest*. Go into massive detail. Lecture the person asking the question.

You can't overkill on most questions. But you don't have to. If you're in a high-churn tag, a good bit of overkill can earn you 100 rep easily. Overkill doesn't work so well in low-churn tags, since overkill relies on many people seeing the sheer massiveness of your answer.

Comment: Overkill as in "I answered this question 2 years late, so I'll write a lot about it." :) Good answer.

Comment: _"Being able to serve the under-served parts of SO [...] also means you get a lot more accepts, rather than just upvotes."_ is just a theoretical thesis. I'm mainly active in two such under-served parts: _maven_, _jenkins_. There are 10 accepted in my recent 60 answers and 37 with zero votes. So you apparently get neither of them there. To be honest: This stresses my altruism and makes it less fun to contribute.

Comment: Most of my reputation goes from overkill answer. But it worked only once in my life, and I write a lot of overkill answers.

Answer (score 27):

[I](https://superuser.com/questions/4368/os-x-equivalent-of-windows-run-box/4383#4383) [know](https://superuser.com/questions/1384/how-to-disable-reassign-the-windows-key/1399#1399) [first](https://superuser.com/questions/16731/16735) [hand](https://superuser.com/questions/21959/is-jailbreaking-an-ipod-touch-just-as-dangerous-as-an-iphone/22123#22123) [that](https://superuser.com/questions/14938/what-advanced-google-search-techniques-have-you-used/14943#14943) #3 is a sure easy way to get more attention to your answer (and in turn more upvotes).

I always do my best to distinguish my answer from all the others by using plenty of [links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/), quotes, **formatting**. Most of the time, this will shoot my question to the top of the list and ensure upvotes a plenty.

Oh, and [especially pictures](https://superuser.com/questions/9120/whats-the-best-way-to-stream-video-from-my-computer-to-my-tv-preferably-wirele/9131#9131):

> http://cache.gawker.com/assets/images/17/2009/07/340x_appletv_boxee.jpg

Comment: yes but that is not a bad thing, good formatting is a net positive

Comment: What you say is indeed mostly true. But the last example could be better — you say *especially pictures*, yet link to an answer with *0* votes ;)

Comment: Jeff: Yes, it is a good thing :).
Jonik: Yeah, it was a horrible example (It actually used to be -1), but it was taking me too long to find a better answer.

Comment: Lousy pictures! Missing freehand circles!

Comment: Love the fact my answer with equal formatting didn't get any upvotes :P http://superuser.com/questions/9120/whats-the-best-way-to-stream-video-from-my-computer-to-my-tv-preferably-wirele/9131#9131

Comment: Ivo: In this case, i think you could have done without a giant XBox on the page. That only deters voters :P

Comment: And the nominations for "Most effective use of an unrelated image" are...

Comment: Links are an important part of formatting. My highest voted answer should be a one-liner, but I added 5 superfluous links and an unnecessary code example. I put the least relevant information first and the most relevant information last. I feel kinda dirty now...

Comment: I think people really like when you put a different link on every word of a phrase. I get hetcha upvotes when I do that.

Comment: [This](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/365/155) answer is a good example on Graphics. It was **not** a good answer to the question, but it gained up-votes because of nice images and formatting. Sadly, this entire question was made community wiki, so it lost the rep-potential...

Comment: Pictures got me 5k on DIY and a couple of K pm SuperUser... in a few months.... I got bored of downloading pictures....

Answer (score 24):

Should we really care about points all the time? I am here for:

1. **Learning**: It can be anything like learning new tips, logic, etc.
2. **For getting my answers**
3. and obviously if you want your answer then do **some favor for others**. Check their questions and try to give them a proper solution for their problem.

*Honestly saying, I don't give a damn about my reputation. This is not a college class where you have to score good marks for good grades or something like that.*

Answer (score 22):

Answer quickly but incorrectly unfortunately works. Sometimes such answers are even hastily marked as best answer.

I suggest sorting answers starting from most recently added, or sort few most recently added above others (this way each answer will be top for at least a moment).

Don't let few up/down votes affect order, at least when question is still new.

```sql
SELECT … FROM answers … ORDER BY 
  (CASE WHEN abs(number_of_votes) > threshold THEN number_of_votes ELSE 0 END),
  (date_added > NOW() - interval '10 minutes') DESC,
  …
```

Comment: `
SELECT *
FROM (
 SELECT *
 FROM answers
 WHERE number_of_votes > THRESHOLD
 ORDER BY
  number_of_votes
 ) q
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    answers
WHERE   number_of_votes <= THRESHOLD
 AND date_added > NOW - '10 minutes'::INTERVAL
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM answers
WHERE number_of_votes <= THRESHOLD
 AND date_added <= NOW() - '10 minutes'::INTERVAL
`

This is more index friendly.

Sorry, just couldn't help it :)

Answer (score 20):

Let me tackle these one at a time.

> Be the First to Answer. Even at the cost of quality.

Absolutely true. Like others have said, this is actually a good thing because getting a quick answer to a problem is typically what you want. The only problem is (as noted by codexon) wrong quick answers can get voted up. Or someone posts something that's irrelevant but correct and gets voted up because people don't seem to understand or don't read the OP's requirements.

> Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically

I don't really like tactical downvoting. I really think downvoting shouldn't be anonymous for this and other reasons. Or as a compromise, downvotes on questions you also answer shouldn't be anonymous. This also includes putting on a downvote and later taking it off. As others have noted, if you want to [rescind](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rescind) a downvote, you can edit the answer (with 3k+ reputation) and you're then allowed to rescind it after the normal time limit.

> Use obnoxious in-your-face formatting and lists.

I don't see how "obnoxious" formatting helps. But there's definitely an advantage to using something other than a "blob" of text. You can break that up with headings, lists and/or images. It also helps to put a useful title in a link instead of just a raw URL.

> Be Aware of the 200 reputation/day Limit

As I think Jon Skeet wrote, you need to get to the 200 reputation cap limit as soon as possible during the day to increase the window for over-200 reputation gains from accepted answers and bounties. I've made numerous posts against the reputation system working like this. I actually think this disadvantages more casual users. After all Jon Skeet won't spend much time during the day in the soft cap region. I read once he said that sometimes when he gets up in the morning he's already at +200 for the day (which is 6-8 hours in for him in the UK).

> Edit, But Don’t Edit Too Much

True again. You don't want to make your posts CW and I have again posted numerous times how I think this owner edit forcing CW is actually a bad thing. It discourages people from maintaining their posts. I've proposed several solutions including edits after 6 not bumping the post but they've all been rejected. I think we should be doing everything we can to encourage people to maintain content they've written and updating it as the facts change.

> Associate your other accounts

This is an easy one.

The only thing I'd add is that you want to judiciously bounty hunt and look for new bounties with low upvote answers. You also want to look for bounties that end late in the "reputation day" as around half the time the OP just lets the bounty lapse without selecting an answer and you know when that will be. No point wasting your time with bounties that end at 1 am UTC.

I'm not sure many bounty posters realize that the top answer only gets half the bounty by auto-acceptance. IMHO we need to encourage active selection of an answer by giving the OP a nominal reputation amount (say 10 points) for selecting an answer rather than auto-selecting.

Basically what's been said is correct. A few of the things I consider negative and should be addressed as described above.

Comment: "As I think Jon Skeet wrote..." Should the reputation system be designed based on the guy with the highest score?  How many people hit the rep cap anyway?  I hit it the other day -- for the first time in my life, and I'm just outside the top 10%..

Comment: By definition those at the top have the most experience, which is noteworthy. But I wasn't putting Jon up as an expert in this context, merely attributing the source.

Answer (score 17):

For an eye-opening read, check out the comments on Reddit. Amusingly enough, someone chose the title of this post as [Why Stack Overflow sucks](http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9dv29/why_stackoverflow_sucks/). My favourite from one [relix](http://www.reddit.com/user/relix):

> I've answered exactly [1 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258187/communication-between-two-flex-apps/1260710#1260710).
>   It was the only correct answer to that
>   question, but it didn't get any votes
>   and didn't get selected as the answer.
>   Instead, the wrong answer was selected
>   and got all the brownie points.
>
> That was the moment I decided never to
>   waste time on Stack Overflow again. Why
>   even bother.

Comment: Before I saw that, I thought nothing can beat youtube comments.

Comment: There are some people that seem to have some pre-existing prejudice to SO that I don't fully understand.

Comment: There are some people that have pre-existing prejudice to everything you can name.

Comment: "I decided never to waste time on StackOverflow again" -> David Verhasselt "Seen  **45 mins ago**".  Tsk.

Comment: @hyperslug, He meant "answering questions".

Comment: Related: *[Why do some people hate Stack Overflow?](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-people-hate-Stack-Overflow)*

Answer (score 15):

I have also written an article on Stack Overflow tips and tricks that can be viewed here:

http://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2010/02/14/stackoverflow-tips-tricks-5/

The main points include:

**1. Get 100 Reputation Points Free**

**2. Add “Interesting” & “Ignored” Tags**

**3. Install a [Greasemonkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) Script**

**4. Be the First to Answer a Question**

**5. Markdown**

**6. Don’t Over-Style Your Answers**

**7. Add Pictures**

**8. Use Google Effectively**

**9. Use JS Bin**

**10. Edit Your Answers Cleverly**

**11. Keep Your References Open**

**12. Involve Yourself to Earn Badges**

Answer (score 14):

1. Be the first to post a ***good answer***. Even at the cost of quality.

   ~ *Post a correct and helpful answer.
   Make it perfect afterwards.*
2. <s>Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically</s>

   ~ *This is wasted effort. Making other answers look worse doesn't make yours better.*
3. Use <s>obnoxious in-your-face</s> formatting and lists ***wisely***.
4. Be aware of the 200 rep/day limit

   ~ *Gain the favor of OP. You will get additional rep for your answers being accepted even after you've hit the cap.*
5. Edit, But Don’t Edit Too Much

   ~ *Prefer fewer but greater edits over many minor ones. Care about those who are already reading it.*
6. <s>Associate your other accounts</s> *- Seriously? ... that desperate?*

   ---

   *+ tips from my experience:*
7. ***Provide additional helpful info related to the matter.***

   ~ *This might include pointing out good / bad practices, pointing out completely different (better) approaches rather than helping to fix the one included in question etc.*

   ~ *Impart the knowledge that OP as well as many **future visitors** will appreciate.*
8. *Help others to make their answers better, collaborate. Be generous, kind and humble.*

   ~ *Others will treat you the same way. Karma is good thing.*

Answer (score 12):

**Warning:** The following contains absurd levels of snark that might be dangerous to the eyes, hands, or soul of a moderately to severely sane reader. I promise there's a point to this at the end. Maybe.

If someone has beat you to the #1 with a one-liner, follow up with some extreme #3 by repeating their answer:

> [Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/189720)'s answer is absolutely correct: Walnuts do taste great with
>   cantaloupe.
>
> Here's a code example that explains it a bit more:
>
> ```
> public class Walnuts extends Cantaloupe implements DeliciousCombination { }
> ```
>
> When writing walnut-related code, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Determine if you need cantaloupes
> 2. Determine if you *have* cantaloupes
> 3. Eat the walnuts **no matter what**
>
> Things to beware about cantaloupes:
>
> - They are less delicious without walnuts
> - They are much heavier than walnuts
> - Fewer people are allergic to cantaloupes than to walnuts
>
> [walnuts.org](http://www.walnuts.org/about-walnuts/), the official specification for walnuts, has this mostly unrelated thing to say about them:
>
> ```
> California grows more than 99% of the country’s supply
> and two-thirds of the world’s walnut trade.
> ```
>
> Additional resources about walnuts and cantaloupe recipes:
>
> [Wikipedia's page on walnuts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walnut), [Wikipedia's page on cantaloupe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantaloupe), [Wikipedia's page when I clicked random article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dry_gallon)
>
> **[Note/Edit/Update/Addendum/tl;dr/Other Indication of Superfluous Footnote]** You should probably get rid of the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29) on line 1000000.

You will get upvoted more than the person who answered first, and you don't even need to know the answer beforehand. As long as you have some experience in the general field and you understand what the answer is saying, you can add completely unnecessary bits and reap the benefits of another person's hard work!

But in all seriousness, I don't think this trick is always bad. You still have to put effort into your code example, lists, quotes, and finding related(ish) links. People upvote because it looks like you put more work into your answer (you might've) and because it's possible your answer is clearer to understand. Though Rule #1 says your answer will probably not get accepted.

Comment: May I suggest reducing some of the snark in this answer? Your last paragraph makes this a decent answer, in my opinion, but someone may not get that far before dismissing it.

Comment: @AndrewBarber You're right. I have this awful habit of burying the lead. Somehow every time I come up with something that I think flows, the most important point is in the last letter of the last word of the last sentence of the overly-long gag. I will try to think of a way to get to the point faster.

Comment: I need to get a handle on my snark problem. Snarkers Anonymous?

Comment: @Eva Get some friends around to help you with "[The Hunting of the Snark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snark_(Lewis_Carroll))"?

Comment: Was it really suppose to be a joke? I see many users make good use of the ways of the Dark Side.

Answer (score 12):

I've seen a user with over 1000 reputation but his writing sounded like a newbie. I looked at his profile and saw 266 questions with lots of upvotes and 11 answers with a total of one upvote.

So the strategy is to ask a LOT of easy questions on popular topics so people can answer and upvote you.

It's freaking sad but at the same time amusing that people are actually mostly hackers. We hack around the system to get what we want. I think that this is very valuable at times but dangerous at other times.

Comment: Indeed and there are [much worse examples](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4653/leora?tab=questions&sort=votes&page=26). 1800 low-quality questions for a total of 10,000 reputation points.

Answer (score 12):

## NOOOOO!!!!! MUST DO DAMAGE CONTROL!!!!!

Seriously though. If you just take some of the "advice" from the linked article as it is, much harm would be done to the ecosystem.

### Re: “Be the First to Answer. Even at the cost of quality.”

This is missing a second part: please make sure you improve your answer after quick-posting it.

### Re: “Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically.”

#### Noooo!!!!

Downvote if and only if an answer is bad. Don't "strategically" downvote because the answer is competing with yours. Plus your down-vote gets [locked in after 5 minutes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38759/225020), so the damage can't be undone unless you commit further evils.

Don't be afraid to call out on an answer that is plain wrong though, via comments and/or downvotes.

### Re: “Use obnoxious in-your-face formatting and lists.”

Well, I won't use the term "obnoxious" ("obnoxious" works pretty well on Meta though)

Just make sure that your post is easy to read. Use proper formatting

- put code or code-related things in code block or inline code span.
- use headers if your post is relatively long to organize things
- use lists when applicable
- if you feel that some related documentation/reference can provide further details, mention it in your question.
- if you're quoting text/explanation from a reference or from a post, put it in blockquotes and give credits.
- for emphasis or highlighting keywords, use italics or bold, but sparingly.

### Re: “Be Aware of the 200 rep/day Limit”

- Fair enough. You don't want to spin your wheels.

### Re: “Edit, But Don’t Edit Too Much”

Don't edit at all unless you have something useful to add or something that needs to be changed. Bumping up your answer just for the sake of drawing attention bumps down other questions that might need attention more than you do.

### Re: “Associate your other accounts”

- Fair enough.

Comment: I think you're missing the tongue-in-cheek nature of this question and its answers...

Comment: Nuh uh, I'm just catering towards users who are taking this "thread" seriously.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding #2, what if you hide votes for the 10 minutes or so?

By "hide", I mean: people can vote, but answers will appear to have 0 score (and time-based sort order) until the 10 minutes are up.

You could even hide timestamps and randomize display order for the initial window, though I'm not sure that would be worth it.

Comment: You would have to randomize the display order. If you simply had it by time, then people would still do tactic 1.

Answer (score 10):

If I can add three more...

1. The highest concentration of SO fanatics (and by natural association, the FGITW's) is on the west coast of the USA, secondarily NYC.  So visit the site when these regions are likely to be asleep and snipe out any questions that would otherwise get nailed in the FGITW rush.  For what it's worth, Jon Skeet is in UTC+0.
2. If you get an accepted answer, go back and look at the tags.  Then look at them again.  Are they the *right* tags?  Are ***all*** the relevant tags present?  Also... On the right side of the page will be a list of 'related' questions. Check the tags on those questions to see if any are relevant towards getting your accepted answer better exposed to the community.
3. Lastly, defensive protection.  Look at the original question carefully.  Are there any improvements that can be made to prevent its closure as a duplicate?  As off topic?  Also, try and  flesh out your answer before the FGITW's get their first caffeine hit.

I have it in mind that these are legitimate whilst simultaneously serving best community interests.

Comment: hmm nice :) @laxmi

Answer (score 8):

Jokes aside there is a certain flaw in the way that reputation is earned.

There are additional factors to how much reputation you'll receive by asking a question or answering one that have nothing to do with the "correctness" of the question/answer.

It helps if you answer quickly, I found that if I answer an open question a day or more after it was posted the chances of getting up voted or chosen are close to nil.
People almost never up vote a question, I think it got something to do with the fact that it's hard to decide if the question is a "good" question.

And of course users that instead of learning or answering questions try to grab as much reputation as possible, I've noticed people using the same dirty tricks explained in the post (like coping an already posted answer and bumping the other question down).

Comment: I have one exception to this rule. I've answered a simple mysql question that regularly brings in upvotes. Still the first security flawed question is way ahead :) But I agree with what you say.

Answer (score 8):

Also, work in popular subject areas.  Most people wouldn't recognize Jon Skeet's name if he had the ability to write swift and excellent answers in Lisp, Haskell, and Delphi, but not anything else.

Pick your questions.  Only answer questions that are easy to read.  If people are turned off from reading the question, they're unlikely to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I think a great way to restrain this behaviour is forcing to leave a comment on downvote.
I think that the downvote comment must be anonymous, for not letting people downvote only for revenge.

In this way if the reason of the downvote is not good enough, a moderator (or everyone using the voting system) can eliminate the downvote (and take measure against the user with this bad behaviour if it persist in time).

Comment: @Brad: What did you not understand?

Comment: The question doesn't ask how to fix the situation.

Comment: Sorry, but with " Walnuts? Cantaloupe? " you weren't too clear of what you're really asking, basically you're asking for opinions, and that's my opinion.

Comment: I love this foolish behaviour, this is a open question (on a meta site) that is barely a question, the OP intention is not clear, but basically it ask for opinion, I gave one, costructive, and I get a downvote...

It's just Amazing! XD

Answer (score 7):

The choice of question is probably the most important point missing from the list - once you have *embellished* your post with enough **obnoxious** formatting, it's all about the number of people who see your question - the more people who see your answer, the more potential votes.

This means that the more popular the question the more upvotes, in particular:

- **Really easy questions** tend to do well - lots of people think that they could have a go at answering it, so it gets lots of views.
- **QUESTIONS WITH THE TITLE IN ALL-CAPS** also do quite well as some people quite enjoy moaning about / closing rubbish questions.
- Questions posted by anyone demi-famous (like **Jeff** or **Jon Skeet**) always attract massive views.
- **Subjective questions** are also great, but you need to get in there early before they become community wiki.

Of course popular questions also means more competition, and so its more important than ever to make sure that you get in early - even so, more popular questions always offer a better vote-to-effort ratio in the long run.

Answer (score 7):

For users who don't have a lot of experience in programming and rarely answer questions, try editing posts.

NOTE: Only suggested edits work, so if you have 2,000 or more reputation, you cannot get reputation from this.

**Tips on Editing**

- **Code Spacing**: Some questions may have code that is spaced more than usual. Try to take advantage of this and space out the code so that it is properly spaced neatly. Using an online compiler is helpful.
- **Grammar Correction**: Some people (most commonly new users) will post bad grammar. Edit that as soon as possible so that the question is good quality.
- **Grave Accents**: Names of methods should use `grave accents` to open and close.
- **Block quotes**: use the `>` followed by any text to block quote the entire line. This is generally used for errors.
- **Titles**: Sometimes the title contains unnecessary words (ie. C# in a question that is tagged C#). Delete those. For unclear titles, they can be fixed.

Comment: **Caution on Editing:** If your edit is not upto the mark, then  sometime you will receive **`edit ban`**

Comment: Well usually these editing techniques work out fine and should be acceptable. My edit percentage is still 90%.

Answer (score 6):

I've seen a corollary to #5: If you're the top answerer, periodically edit the question to bring more attention and votes to your post.  That way, your own answer never becomes wiki.

For the most part it seems accurate.  I'm not sure you could call it gaming since this is already known tacitly condoned.

Reputation is a system that happens to motivate many people well, and it has produced great results.  Coming up with strategies to maximize it while not really contributing is unfortunate, but bearable considering the advantages.

Comment: I guess it largely depends on whether each edit is actually warranted and useful; periodically making trivial, non-consequential edits could more readily be considered gaming. (But if someone does a series of thoroughly useful edits, it *might* be partly gaming, or he might have the purest of intentions - others cannot really know.)

Comment: Linking to the question from other, related questions can accomplish the same thing. Provided they're worthwhile references / edits, i don't see a problem with either.

Answer (score 6):

Most of the answers given here are about how to manipulate things to favor you, get more exposure for your answers, get to easy to answer questions faster and such. But I think an important tip, to maintain the integrity of the forum, is to make sure that you're knowledgeable about the subject matter you want to answer questions on. It does nobody any good if you try to answer questions with BS just so you can be first.

If you're an expert on a particular topic, your well-crafted, timely answers to difficult questions should earn you reputation, not just initially, but over time as well. After enough time, a person like this could eventually get 200 reputation a day just from residual upvotes on past answers, and that to me seems like a good position to be in. You're likely not going to achieve that with an "answer as fast as possible" strategy with low quality answers on low quality questions.

Answer (score 5):

### Some examples that seem to work for me.

- **Provide a detailed analysis of the question.**

  - [Why doesn’t the .* consume the entire string in this Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323613/why-doesnt-the-consume-the-entire-string-in-this-perl-regex/1323700#1323700)
  - [Obfuscation Puzzle: Can you figure out what this Perl function does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100106/obfuscation-puzzle-can-you-figure-out-what-this-perl-function-does/147456#147456)
  - [How do I compare two strings in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175390/how-do-i-compare-two-strings-in-perl/1175418#1175418)

- **Asking why the question doesn't do the preferred method.**

   This can be difficult to get right. If you come off as mean, people will down-vote your answer, instead of up-voting it.

  - [In Perl, why do I get a “syntax error” when I try to use string eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227605/in-perl-why-do-i-get-a-syntax-error-when-i-try-to-use-string-eval/1227950#1227950)

- **Post an answer that does what the OP wants, but the way it should be done.**

   Specifically, not what the OP is asking.

  - [How can I reference a hash with a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1240796/how-can-i-reference-a-hash-with-a-variable-name/1240849#1240849)

- **Post multiple answers that are significantly different.**

   For example to the question [Regular Expression to match valid dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates), I posted three different answers.

  - [This one shows how to write it maintainably in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates/60890#60890)
  - [I also wrote an expanded version of the answer provided in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates/60869#60869)
  - [I even wrote an answer using a Perl 6 rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51224/regular-expression-to-match-valid-dates/60899#60899)
  - I might even write a [Perl 6 grammar](http://perlcabal.org/syn/S05.html).

Answer (score 5):

**1. Be the First to Answer. Even at the cost of quality.**

Instead, randomize the order of the answers while the question is new. In addition, hide the up-vote/down-vote count as to not influence the other readers (i.e. lemming effect). Eventually transition the question back to normal view. The rate of activity on the question should determine the length before standard view is enabled.

Comment: This just optimizes SO for those who want to play games, at the expense of those who actually wish to use it for Q&A.

Comment: @Shog9 I disagree: this would reduce the short term benefit of the first answer with some up votes compared to later answers that may have been more thought out and/or referenced.

Answer (score 4):

I know people disagree with [#2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6460/if-you-just-witnessed-tactical-downvoting-is-it-a-reportable-offense). I disagree with #1 but I know it sometimes holds true. The others seem somewhat accurate.

Comment: #2 is the only one I disagree with to the point of considering some algorithmical way of blocking it

Comment: #2 just seems like temporary result-manipulating similar to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15746/voting-primarily-a-reward-for-the-user-or-a-sorting-correctness-method. In time the best answers will bubble up.

Answer (score 3):

#1 is very true, but could maybe be alleviated by *just receiving* answers for a reasonably short amount of time (say 5 min) after the question was posted -- *without* displaying them. Then, these first answers could be shown in random order. This might take a little pressure away and encourage people to put some more efforts in their first try.

Comment: I feel that the asker getting a fast response is much more useful and valuable than tweaking the system to discourage gaming reputation.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73/is-the-fastest-gun-in-the-west-solved/93#93 for a slightly different take on that idea.

Answer (score 3):

**2. Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically**

See my response to #1. I think that will help curb this. Another solution is to increase downvote cost if you have already answered the question. If the user downvotes before answering, then either revert the user's downvotes for the question, apply the new "cost" of the downvotes to the user after answering the question. This could be a confirmation the user has to agree to after clicking "submit". For example: "*Answering this question will remove X reputation due to downvotes assigned to competing answers. Continue?*"

Comment: Disagree. I sometimes downvote other answers on questions I have answered because the other answers are seriously wrong. I remember one question for alternative ways to determine whether .NET objects were equal, and there was an upvoted answer advising using GetHashCode [which is utterly wrong according to the docs]. It would have hurt a little to lose extra rep for downvoting that.

Answer (score 3):

What's the use of these reputations anyway? I became a member of SoF to find quality answers for my questions and if somebody has a question that I might know the answer, help him to find the answer. I know that it is enjoyable to gain respect among the fellow programmers, but I think that is not the goal. It's not a race for gaining more reputations but it's a game of helping each other to improve our knowledge. We are not players against each other but we are members of a team playing to gain the knowledge and skills that we need to be even better programmers.

Comment: To me it is primarily a game, the Q&A is just a nice bonus.  I dislike reading about the crap I do in my day job, but I love games.

Answer (score 2):

Others answered well how to continue, but here's my strategy for the very start: Not everyone is good in programming, but there are lots of sites on the Stack Exchange network and odds are good that you are good at something we have a site for.

Pick a topic you know enough about to be able to give good answers, read their tour, lurk around for a while and answer wherever you have something helpful to say (protip: early betas have less traffic, so you have more time to answer before someone else does and you don't have to watch duplicate answers too much). After a few days return to Stack Overflow with association bonus of +100 points allowing you to chat, comment and upvote, privileges whose lack annoys the most.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think about those suggestions:

> 1. Be the First to Answer. Even at the cost of quality.

Absolutely not. It's happened several times that I started writing an answer to an unanswered question, which took time since I was writing high-quality answers. While I was writing, others had time to answer before me and sometimes even got upvotes. But I just continued writing my answer, and when I posted it, it got more upvotes than the others and sometimes even got accepted. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41778214/4284627) is a concrete example.

Also, if you have a good answer to an old question, don't hesitate to post it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31428921/4284627) is my highest upvoted non-meta post on the whole Stack Exchange network, and it was posted 6 years after the question was asked. It's even the answer to that question with the most upvotes, it even outscored the acceped answer. Of course, it took time to collect all those upvotes, but in the long term I earned a whole lot of reputation from it. And I still see from time to time a +10 in my profile page because someone upvoted it.

> 2. Use Downvotes and Comments Strategically

What? Abuse the system? No way. I don't know how comments can be used strategically, but [tactical downvoting is wrong](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/24166/349538). It might earn you reputation, but it's not very nice. Answers should be downvoted because they're wrong or low quality, not because someone else who posted an answer wants his answer to be on the top. Also, if you abuse the system too much, you might risk being suspended (I don't know what the exact criteria are, but I'm not planning on trying it).

> 3. Use obnoxious in-your-face formatting and lists.

Format your posts well. That way, they will be easier to read and therefore more useful. But even if the post is badly formatted, someone will probably edit it sooner or later. The question is how many people didn't upvote your post in the mean time because they thought it was ugly. Anyway, it doesn't take a huge effort to format correctly, so why not do it?

> 4. Be Aware of the 200 rep/day Limit

I've never earned that much reputation in one single day, so for me it's not that important. However, for someone like Jon Skeet, it would probably be useful.

> 5. Edit, But Don’t Edit Too Much

This depends on how much reputation you have:

- If you have more than 2000 reputation, editing doesn't affect your reputation at all, so you can edit as much or as little you want, it doesn't make any difference.
- If you have less than 2000 reputation, edit a lot since each approved edit gives you 2 reputation. But make sure that your edit is good, otherwise it will be rejected and rejected edits don't give any reputation. Also, it's better to edit posts of decent quality that aren't likely to get deleted, since every time a post you edited gets deleted, you lose the 2 reputation that you earned from editing it. So editing an answer saying "i hav the same prombem plzzzz help" into "I have the same problem please help" won't do you much good.

> 6. Associate your other accounts

That's a great idea. If you associate your accounts and earn 200 reputation on one of them, you will automatically earn 100 reputation on all of them, even on the one where you earned 200 reputation. The only problem is that that only happens once. But it's better than not at all.

---

In addition to this, I have my own tips on how you can earn a lot of reputation. These tips made me earn a lot of reputation on Stack Overflow.

7. **Once you have the privilege to review, review a lot**

In the review, you can come across posts that can make you earn reputation. If you have less than 2000 reputation, there are a lot of posts by people who are bad in English just waiting for you to edit them. For each post that you edit, you earn 2 reputation. If you edit a lot of posts, you will earn a lot of reputation.

You might even come across some question that you can answer. That's happened to me several times and each time I came across a question that I could answer, I answered it and my answer most of the time got accepted and a few upvotes. If this happens regularly, you will end up earning a lot of reputation.

8. **On Stack Overflow, participate in documentation**

Look around in the Stack Overflow documentation to see if there is something you can improve. Every time your change gets approved, not only do you earn 2 reputation for the approval itself, but if you edit enough, you also earn 5 reputation for each upvote on that topic and 5 reputation each time someone references the topic in an upvoted answer.

Introductory topics are especially good for this, since they get upvoted often. Edit a few introductory topics in some popular languages, and then enjoy the +5's appearing on your screen every day.

---

To conclude:

1. Post high-quality answers, and don't get discouraged if someone else answers before you
2. Never abuse the system
3. Format your posts correctly
4. If you're Jon Skeet, be aware of the 200 rep/day limit; if you're Donald Duck, concentrate on the other tips
5. Edit a lot, especially if you have less than 2000 reputation
6. Associate your other accounts
7. Once you have the privilege to review, review a lot
8. On Stack Overflow, participate in documentation

I think that the most important ones are #1 (my version), #7 and #8 (Stack Overflow only). If you have less than 2000 reputation, #5 is also important.

Answer (score 0):

### Weekend effect

Most "hard" sites tend to have two large groups:

1. The professionals of the site topics
2. Enthusiasts

If you belong to (2), it is much more hard for you to get reputation.

*But: the professionals are tend to be far, far away on the weekend. This opens the gates before the commoners.*

Here is the time, as you can activate yourself, to concentrate your effort. Look for the enthusiasts. Here is the time to get your first mortherboard badge.

Note: if you want to get the mortarboard badge, or to hit the repcap, you have to start the day early.

If you are a professional, then it is the possibility to get your first motherboard badge without working on it on all the day.

Answer (score -1):

Not

- formating

And

## Spalling

well
(incoroect)[hyperlionks]

1. And general usessness
   Of {posts}(0)