# Vote to delete answers

Tags: discussion, answers, vote-to-close

Why aren't answers held to the same rules as questions?

Answers can only be flagged, or voted upon. We see many examples of new-to-Stack Overflow-users posting comments, questions, and follow-ups as answers to their own questions. Why can't we vote to delete as "Not a valid Answer," or other reasons?

I don't think downvotes should be the solution here, as I'm not a fan of punishing the many new-to-Stack Overflow-users who unknowingly do these types of things.

Possible Restrictions:

- You must have 3k rep to vote for answer-deletion.
- You cannot delete an answer that has +2 upvotes.

Comment: In my case, I downvoted because I don't think we should be able to do this.

Comment: *Insert rant of how meta discourages feedback*

Comment: "Stop thinking my opinions are wrong! I'm guaranteed the right of freedom of expression so you have to accept my ideas!" ffffffffffff Hippies! I'm covered in hippies! They're biting my shins and elbows with their sharp vegetarian teeth optimized for biting carrots and cucumbers and other long, cylindrical, hard vegetables. Get them off of me! I don't deserve this.

Comment: @Welbog, Vegan teeth. Sharpened for eating nuts and seeds. They can also crack coconuts on their own foreheads.

Comment: @Jonathan: If you can't close answers with more than 2 upvotes, then why are you concerned? They will already be near the bottom of the list.

Comment: Answers aren't always sorted by votes. And an invalid answer at the bottom of the list is still an invalid answer. I'm not a fan of isolating noise to the bottom of the page - I'm a fan of eliminating it altogether :)

Comment: Why on earth would someone who is offended by down votes not be offended if you vote to delete their answer?

Comment: Downvotes remove reputation. A deletion does not.

Comment: Why can't we downvote comments? ;-)

Comment: If you're going to put those restrictions on it, shouldn't there be a time limit as well? Wouldn't be hard to have an answer deleted before it was even given the chance to be upvoted. Either way, downvoting an answer works just fine, then the user can just delete it to save himself the reputation cost.

Comment: Deleting a question certainly does remove reputation. It removes 100 reputation. Why would an answer be any different?

Comment: This is like saying "I don't want to hurt new driver's feelings by issuing them a ticket for disobeying traffic laws, instead I just want to impound their car."

Comment: Because it's more difficult to accidentally post a non-question as a question. Users screw up answers because they are used to forums, and used to appending future messages. That should be kept in consideration. This isn't the case with posting a brand new question.

Comment: It is just as easy to post a non answer as an answer. This has be demonstrated numerous times. Down votes work just fine to fix these, along with the occasional need to flag for mod attention.

Comment: OH NO! Someone has decremented my arbitrary number by two! How will I go on!

Comment: Rich, accidentally posting a non-question is more difficult because it's the first action. Accidentally posting an answer is easier as there's already a flow behind what you're doing.

Comment: And could you please learn to discuss these things as an adult, without these superficial childish tantrums?

Comment: @Rich B: With therapy, and the support of friends and family, you may eventually be able to get past this trauma and live a normal live.

Comment: Asking a question requires clicking on "Ask a question" and then being on a page with all the rules and everything on it. Posting an answer requires typing into the box at the bottom of every question and clicking the submit button. I wish you had as much of a clue about this 'flow' as you pretend to have.

Comment: Adults discuss things without constantly whining about their feelings and calling valid points made by other adults 'superficial childish tantrums' when they realize they have no valid argument to stand on. It is a classic argument deconstruction that makes you look silly and your argument look invalid. Not like this argument needed any help with that.

Comment: Rich, the "superficial tantrum" was your "OH NO! How will I go on!" statement. That is simply immature. Secondly, asking a question is done in the absense of previous events. Nobody has said anything before you ask a question. Posting an answer is done in the context of a pseudo-discussion. Somebody asked a question (you sometimes), and you instinctively answer it. Somebody answers your question, and you want to "answer" theirs. If we ignore the context, and consider only the number of steps, then making a sandwich can be as easy as changing a car tire. Now please, curb the sarcasm.

Comment: I just cannot believe how a supposed adult cannot understand basic adult communication to the point where they think a valid response to a valid argument against them is to cry about perceived immaturity and sarcasm in comments not directed at them. Somehow, considering the source, I am not all that surprised I guess.

Comment: @Rich, how is "OH NO! How will I go on" a "valid response"?

Comment: Argument Rulebook Entry #1: When in trouble with standing your ground on an argument, ignore all responses and concentrate on anything you can try to express as 'immature' or 'sarcastic'. Ignore logic and assume that somehow invalidates the other person's argument or further validates your argument. Never actually debate the points, just cry about your unfair treatment in the hands of humor.

Comment: Making a sandwich is just about as easy as changing a car tire, with the proper implements.  1) take the tire off 2) put the new one on.  1) get out the ingredients 2) slap that bitch together.

Comment: @belgariontheking Is pulling a tire out of the trunk as easy as moving a slice of bread from a bag? No, that is precisely my point. Don't equate simplicity with steps.

Comment: @Rich,            Really?

Comment: Argument Rulebook Entry #2: When your argument is all out of steam, keep spamming the same gibberish, nonsense, straw man arguments. If no one can understand what the hell you are talking about, you win!

Comment: I generally have more ingredients in my sandwiches than bread.  Then again, I'm employed, so YMMV.  "get out the ingredients" is getting them all out of the cabinets, fridge, etc. and is roughly as much work as using a pneumatic drill to remove the old tire.  Slapping that bitch together is roughly as difficult as using a pneumatic drill to put the bolts on on a new tire.

Comment: @btk: What are you saying about bread sandwiches? They are only for poor people? You are such a racialist.

Comment: @Rich: And for people with four mortgages.

Comment: Argument Rulebook Entry #76 - Always play like a champion...no excuses.

Comment: related (possibly even a duplicate): [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't this just open up the site to abuse? You could find a really good answer, copy it and then vote to close the "duplicate" original in favour of your own? I don't see the value in this feature. Downvoting an answer rather than voting to close it allows people to see good and bad answers in an argument, if you close all the bad answers, you have no contrast to learn from.

Also, closing a question means closing it for further answers, and in some cases, results in the question being deleted (if it's not real or not programming related for example - SO-wise). What does closing an answer do? Stop it being edited?

Comment: Surely you don't think a single user will have the authority to delete an answer?

Comment: I'm sure someone that vindictive can fake a few other accounts or get some friends in on it. It's not unprecedented.

Comment: That type of behavior can already take place. That's what we have algorithms in place, for detecting who is doing what.

Answer (score 15):

1. It's not as common for answers to be off-topic.
2. When answers are off-topic, spam flags, downvotes and moderator attention whinings are good enough.
3. This is pretty much what downvotes are for.
4. **Vampires** (filling in my bold quota for this answer to guarantee acceptance)

Picture of a vampire, as the commenters required it:

[image: SUPER VAMPIRE]

Comment: I was going to add my own answer, but I realized that you'll just strategically downvote it, so I'll just upvote yours.  Yours was the fastest anyway.

Comment: Here's some context for anyone who happens upon this months from now and mistakenly thinks my comment above is serious: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stackoverflow-reputation-fast

Comment: 5. Profit!

Comment: Don't worry, Bill. No-one thinks you are serious!

Comment: @John: I can't take that chance. :)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard ♦: That's know to have happen.

Comment: @Bill I'm very disappointed in your accusations, especially from a man in your position.

Comment: @Welbog: That looks nothing like @wood!

Comment: @Rich B: My fault. I requested *a* vampire, not *the* Vampire.

Comment: +1 for the vampire pic, -1 because I can't recognise it as vampire. +1 for taking the efford, net worth +1. Congressatiolations or whatever. :-)

Comment: lol @ "bold quota"

Comment: @Alex: -1 to you for not being able to spell a simple word like 'effort'.

Comment: Hey, there are plenty of errors in this post and all you notice is efford? :-)

Comment: @Alex: That combined with your use of 'recognise' made me decide that reading any further would be a futile effort.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is kind of completed,

since users with 20k+ user can vote to delete answers with score of -1 or lower

https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user

Answer (score 4):

**NO**

Downvote, post a comment saying "this is a comment, not an answer" and instruct the user to edit their Question or whatever needs to be done.  A downvote is not punishment.  Deleting their content would be punishment.

Comment: Man, I wish more people would think like this and stop being crybabies about down votes.

Answer (score 3):

Downvotes are the way to get rid of answers.

The reason that questions need close/delete votes and systems is that they occupy clog up the front page and they are the basis of the site. It makes sense that there would be systems in place for this. For answers, you just downvote the person into oblivion.

Comment: I don't think down-voting a new user is a great way to make them feel welcomed. Especially if they don't yet know how to use the system.

Comment: If downvotes offend enough to stop someone using the site, perhaps they have other issues to attend to before interacting with the big wide world.

Comment: Jonathan, closing and deleting their answers would make them feel just as unwelcome. As long as you downvote and comment, or perhaps comment only, then they'll still be able to grow from what they are told. The "closing/deleting" aspect will not help with this. It does not add anything extra.

Comment: Deleting an answer should not hurt their reputation.

Comment: @devinb: +1 I hear way more vehement arguments regarding the closing of people's questions than the down votes on them. With down votes you only get whiny little cry babies asking "Why the downvote?" in the comment of every post they get down voted on.