# How to handle answers that are duplicates of existing answers

Tags: support, review, answers, duplicate-questions, low-quality-posts

The following answer hit the low quality post queue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33472146/2312877

Now the answer is extremely similar to many of the already upvoted answers on the question, most of which are from 2009 - but in addition the linked answer provided no explanation to the code, whereas the upvoted answers did.

The "Recommend Deletion" comments don't really fit, so I don't know if it's valid to recommend deletion, but I wouldn't say the answer "Looks Ok" either.

What should be done (if anything) in cases like this?

EDIT

The answer has since been removed apparently, but either way I've been bit by the automated audit function before in the LQP queue, so I wanted to try to understand what the outcome of situations like this would be - sure you can downvote the answer as one of the comments on this question stated, but that doesn't really help with the queue.

Comment: see also [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/165773)

Answer (score -1):

From the perspective of the Low Quality Posts Queue:

If you find a post in a queue, you need to judge the post based on it's quality. *Not* whether it is wrong. *Not* whether it may simply duplicate another answer. This is simply not the purpose of the low quality queue. If an answer attempts to answer a question, then it's fine, and deserves to stay.

---

From the perspective of the Random Passerby:

Yeah, it's annoying. But sometimes, these posts may look the same, but say something different, even if minor. Have you considered that one might supply an answer from a new version?

Unless an answer is blatantly, and obviously plagiarized, again, let it stand. Keep good faith, and assume good intentions. The author of the answer likely was just trying to help. If you think the answer is helpful or useful, show them some appreciation, and up vote :)

---

From the perspective of the blue blob (i.e. Me):

Well, I can't say anything, since I don't have [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) on Stack Overflow :/