# What is the easist way to get some quick reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Efficient reputation strategy…](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/efficient-reputation-strategy)

I have tried the usual stuff. I just want to quickly get enough rep to be able to upvote, downvote, and comment without being annoyed by pernicious error messages.

Comment: Looks like your SO account currently has over 100 rep, which should be enough to avoid the most pernicious messages. What messages are you seeing, specifically?

Comment: yes I just got over 100 rep! I am happy now. No idea what I did to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer obvious questions, and answer a lot of them.

For an example, see this question.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried answering questions well and correctly?

It seems you've left out what you consider to be "the usual stuff" here.

If you don't put in the knowledge and time to answer well or craft clear questions, the community, aka *the system*, won't reward you with any rep.

If you're not doing either of these simple acts, why should you be allowed to upvote, or even downvote, other people's contribution and work?

Comment: yes, that is what I meant by the usual stuff. I am not looking for John Skeet reputation here, just enough to not be constantly annoyed by my inability to do simple non-malicious tasks.

Comment: +1 -- @John -- You've got to give first. Until you have either submitted an interesting question or two or a few good quality answers, the system/community doesn't think you ought to be impacting other folks rep.

Comment: +1 for the "got to give first"

Answer (score 9):

We don't want people to get quick easy rep.

Answer (score 3):

Writing titles without typos is a possibility. Answering questions correctly is also acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Click the unanswered button and do a lot of research to help.