# Average upvotes per posts on all sites

Tags: support, voting

I want to see what site has on average the most upvotes on posts.

This would be:

(*Number of total upvotes - downvotes* / *Number of posts*)

Comment: Why are you following this order? Why not just upvotes/number of posts? This is the equivalent of (total votes - downvotes)/posts. Subtracting downvotes after dividing is confusing.

Comment: @Catija true, is there anyway to access such a report

Comment: SEDE should have most of the votes, if you know SQL. https://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Catija I don’t

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/979549/average-upvotes-downvotes-per-post-on-all-sites), the top two sites are two metas with a 'score' of about 9.4; [TeX - LaTeX Meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/) and [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) and [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/) are the top main sites with scores of almost 9.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't include deleted posts. Skeptics has pretty high standards for both questions and answers, so what doesn't meet the standard is usually deleted. (Like I said [the last time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311935/323179) this came up—but since then I earned the 10k privilege and I can personally confirm that there are like 6 deleted posts on many of the old questions that accrued over the years.)

Comment: Some of the sites are also very famous on HNQ (e.g. Skeptics, ex-IPS, TWP, Scifi, Academia)... wonder what the result will be if upvotes on HNQ can be ignored... (but that's theoretically impossible since there's no indicator for HNQ on SEDE)

Comment: @Laurel you're right, thank you, and votes on deleted posts *were* counted. I've updated the query and the results are indeed different now.