# How do I earn more reputation and faster?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast) 
>   [Efficient reputation strategy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/efficient-reputation-strategy)

How do I earn more reputations and faster? (Like by asking questions, answering questions, voting on other persons' answers, etc.)

Comment: Post great questions and answers.

Comment: Earn some bounties.

Comment: Searching before asking is a good way *to keep* reputation.

Comment: And is it possible to lose reputation and how?

Comment: @ComputerGeek - You lose reputation be accruing downvotes. The reason you have downvotes on this question is because you didn't search through the tens of hundreds of other questions already asked on this topic. See [Privileges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) and the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).

Comment: *"And is it possible to lose reputation and how?"* ***Read the FAQ, already!*** That's what it is for. Sheesh!

Comment: I think it would be nicer if people won't downvotes to newbies and discourage them to visit these helpful websites again and again.

Comment: It would be nice if newbies read the FAQ - it even explains that downvotes on meta are different. You would know that if you bothered reading the FAQ.

Comment: ComputerGeek: I know it feels like you are being picked on, but this post is pure noise in a already uncomfortably busy administrative effort. People took the time to write lengthy and highly informative documentation in order to give new users a way to find these things out for themselves and you have just given that effort a pointless cold shoulder. In short, *you are being rude to us*. I'm sorry, but that is the way it is.

Comment: [How does reputation work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work) enumerates all the ways you can gain and lose rep and what the limits are.

Answer (score 3):

Answering questions with bounties well is the fastest way to gain reputation.

Just ask [MrGomez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/517815/mrgomez) - he was worried that he was gaining it so fast that he [posted a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127021/is-excessive-bounty-hunting-good-etiquette).

Comment: Wow. (re MrGomez, Bounty Hunter)

Comment: @ShawnChin - Yep. Rather incredible. Good man.