# How to gain rep (new users)?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

Seems like a stupid question, but I'm after a nice solid answer if possible.

I joined SO a while ago to ask the odd question, but recently I'm starting to use it more often.

I've been reviewing the 40 max items (20 first posts/20 late answers) per day, and editing anything I see wrong with them (lots of +2's)... flagging them... etc.

I've also been [using my max 40 votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169868/195862) per day.

But other than commenting where I can and answering the odd question, I'm only [slowly gaining rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1563422/danny-beckett?tab=reputation&sort=post&StartDate=2013-03-03%2021:41:14Z) (1k at the moment).

I might just be overeager, but I was hoping some high-rep users might be able to write a little something on how they earned their stripes?

I've [searched Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=gain%20rep), and to be honest I was hoping I'd get a hit, because it sounds like a stupid question... anyways, here you go!

Also, I'm not referring to how to gain rep on Meta, since it's a bit of a fluke I've earned the rep I have on here. I'm asking about main SO.

Comment: And there's http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21463/efficient-reputation-strategy

Comment: There is no special way to gain rep. The best (and correct) way is to ask really good questions and to give really good answers to other questions.

Comment: P.s. 1k rep in 7 months is not all that bad.

Comment: @Bart Nice, thanks for the link! I've also voted to close this. P.S. I think most of it's only been within the last month.

Comment: Just try to be helpful. Helpful answers beget reputation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ask and Answer Questions!** You get:

- +5 reputation for every upvote you get on a question you asked.
- +10 reputation for every upvote you get on a question you *answered*.
- +15 when an answer you posted gets accepted.

Posting quality answers/questions is the quickest (and also, the best, since you're helping out!) way to get reputation points, and advance with privileges.

**[Read more: How does reputation work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)**