# Reputation Points

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

I'm a brand new user and a first timer to this type of site - I like to use all the resources available when I have a question or a problem (research, google, bing, etc.) so I came here when I got my first real road block in my script where I couldn't find the answer anywhere, but I can't use many of the features (ex: chat) on this site until someone, somehow finds my question in the mist of many, answers it, or gives enough 1 ups... Why is that? How are we supposed to build Reputation when it seems questions by new users are a needle in a haystack to find because they have little or no Reputation? Just curious...

```
    P.S. I saw "How does “Reputation” work?" and "How to gain rep (new users)?"
    before posting my question and I didn't mean for it to appear that I was asking a 
    duplicate question, sorry)
```

In order to clarify, I just wondered if there was a way to improve this wonderful site to make it easier and more helpful on us newbies who know basic to little knowledge of JavaScript who design websites as hobby?

By the way great site before becoming a member the search engine I used always put this site at the top of their list and I was able to find many useful answers to solve my code issues. Thank-you.

My Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17999733/2642910

Comment: Duplicate: How does reputation work?

Comment: Ask good questions. Post good answers. Let the community do the rest (we scale quite well so far).

Comment: The [help] on every site has a section on what reputation is, and what privileges are and how to earn them here. You should always start with the FAQ or help or About pages on every site before you start trying to participate there.

Comment: Also see: [Efficient reputation strategy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/21463)

Comment: By the way, we don't have to know who you are or that you exist in order for you to earn reputation. We just have to come across your questions and/or answers. If they're helpful, we'll vote for them. It really is that easy! It just takes a bit of persistence to rack up big points.

Answer (score 4):

You say:

> I can't use many of the features on this site until someone, somehow finds my question, answers it, or gives me enough 1 ups.

But you've only asked 1 question, and you haven't answered any. So far you've got 6 rep.

Why not answer a couple of questions, or ask some more questions?

Comment: Keep at it @RustyJS! You'll soon be captured by the love of Stack Overflow! ...apart from those who hate Fridays :p