# How to gain reputation more rapidly on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

I'm just wondering: how can I raise my Stack Overflow reputation at faster pace?

Any useful tips from the masters?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast

Comment: It is just a number.  Isn't helping the people who need help more important?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer: It's not *about* maxing out your reputation, but about giving quality answers and learning something yourself.

Otherwise, you can sit on stackoverflow all day, keep answering basic questions in your chosen tags, and you'll probably end up with a high rep pretty quickly, but that doesn't make you good at those languages. It just means you got lots of upvotes.

My advice? You've got the wrong approach. Not everyone on here has the time to post all hours to every question, thus it is perfectly possible for there to be experts floating around with low(er) rep scores. In fact, I've seen some pretty astounding answers given by sub 1k accounts which have at most one or two votes in spite of the difficulty of the topic in question.

Remember what reputation is:

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you.

In order to get that, you're going to need to hang around and give quality answers. There is no short cut to the community trusting you, just as there is no shortcut to becoming a good programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Not a master at all here, but answer questions that you know the answers to as accurately and friendly as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much know your stuff and get answering peoples questions.  Vote ups and getting awarded the answer is the quickest way.  Unfortunately, there are no shortcuts.  Another way is asking questions that others like.  These votes will add points too.

Answer (score 2):

Answering more questions well is the obvious path to high rep. (Key point there is that your answers have to be good.)

You can earn bonus rep if you write great answers to questions with a bounty on them and get awarded that bounty.