# Add +2 reputation points for accepted flagging as duplicate

Tags: feature-request, reputation, duplicate-questions

This question is similar to:
[Why there isn't reputation points for successful flagging?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80852/why-there-isnt-reputation-points-for-successful-flagging)
, but with a small refinement,

- only first flag will get +2 reputation
- only accepted and committed flag will get the reward (this is: question got closed as duplicate, for example)
- only 'exact duplicate' and 'offtopic -> move to other sub-site..' flags will be eligible for bonus.

Rationale:

- there is a high volume of newbie questions appearing each day, which are already answered, sometimes answered at epic level.
- because answering such question can give a person +25 reputation from the noob, not counting random by-passers' good will - people are not very willing to mark such questions as duplicate, and sometimes deliberately copy-paste answers from older duplicates.
- offensive, spammy or retarded questions are downvoted with passion anyway, so there is no need to additionally reinforce users to do that ;)

Comment: @lunboks indeed, a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, the irony...

Comment: So, do I get +2 for copy/pasting lunboks's link into the close box? :)

Comment: @Mat Well, to be fair, it'd have to reward the guy who cast the first stone, be it flag or vote. Otherwise, an enterprising 10k user could just write a script that blindly follows up every dupe flag from the queue with an automatic close vote (if it would be the first one).