# What is the easiest way of increasing reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/171725)

I want to increase my reputation on Stack Overflow, so I would impress my friends at work into join the site, but I haven't been very successful.

I've tryed to answer a lot of questions, and made a few of my own too, but I hardly get an upvote or a comment on my answers.

I want to know if there is an easy way, or if only a lot of time and effort are the secrets to raise reputation.

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/171725) answers my question.

Comment: Uh. Contributing great answers and asking interesting questions, I should think. Stack Overflow isn't a game where you can just jump on a turtle shell indefinitely for free 1-ups.

Comment: I know it's not a game, but I was checking some profiles and realized some people with little rep get few upvotes for great questions, while the ones with high rep sometimes get tons of upvotes for not so interesting questions.

Comment: No need to downvote this into oblivion IMO - it's a fair question for a newcomer. See e.g. [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204)

Comment: @Pekka Thanks for the tip. I wish I had found that question earlier.

Comment: Little known fact that might surprise you: all high-rep users started at 1. No no, it's true.