# Earning reputation when approaching new privileges

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, community

This may just be paranoia but it always seems to me that as I reach new privileges, reputation  becomes scarce. It almost makes me suspicious that fellow Stackonians are reserving their up votes for only the most righteous of questions and answers when they recognize how close you are to reaching another privilege. Has anyone else experienced this type of trend?

Now, assuming there is some of this behavior occurring, the other question becomes: Is this true to the spirit of what earning reputation is about?

Comment: What would the reason to up-vote 20k users be, then? `:-)`

Comment: @kiamlaluno That is more a means to show how promiment the user is as a respected figure in the community. I don't think it debunks the possibility of what I am talking about.

Comment: See [Six Simple Tips for Earning Reputation Fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: I noticed the same thing, but I guess it's just like time slowing down when Christmas approaches...

Comment: I'm the other way round - there have been times when I've been really pleased to give an upvote if it ticks someone over a threshold. It's the SO equivalent of seeing the odometer in your car rolling over to another 10,000.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't say I have noticed this at all, no. In fact I notice the opposite: The more rep I get the easier it is to acquire more; people upvote questions/answers from people with higher rep more easily.

I think what's really going on is that you're more anxious for your new privs and things you have to wait for seem to take longer :-)

I really don't think people take the time to check your rep, think about what privs they'd be granting you if they voted, and vote based on that. I suppose it might happen sometimes, but I hardly think it's common.

Now if you have *evidence* of your claims, please do provide!

Actually, I have some evidence *against* your claim. Take a look at your reputation gains since September:

[image: FHC REP FOR MORE REPS!!!]

The time when reputation was *most* "scarce" for you was in september. You're nearly at 3K, which is when you get to cast close votes. As you've neared 3K, you're started to earn *more reputation* that you did back in September.

Amirite?

Comment: Unhandled Exeption Haha well that may very well have some truth. So does your statement about rep gaining more rep .. which seems to follow money makes more money concept. But, I don't know if I am convinced =P

Comment: I did not know about this graph feature lol. I don't look at my break down very often anymore and didn't know they added that. Pretty nice. Ok I concede =P

Comment: It's (somewhat) new... but it's just a redesign, there's been some sort of graph forever. Related: [Recent feature changes to stack exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445)

Answer (score 9):

[image: infographical response]

I can't really think of a good reason why anyone would be concerned about a given user receiving a certain privilege to the point where they wouldn't apply their typical voting behaviour when coming across one of their posts. A lot of people are simply here for the information, so that seems like an obscure thing for them all to worry about.

If there was actually an observable trend - which, as The Unhandled Exception [pointed out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115228/150235), there might not be - you're far more likely to find a correlation to overall voting trends, or to personal activity (such as the types of questions you're answering, and so on).

That's not to say that [someone isn't out to get you](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38090/why-are-assassins-coming-after-me), but it's unlikely to be voters on Stack Overflow.

Comment: That is a very good point. +1

Comment: +1 for *Why are assassins coming after me?* -- I have been running from those pesky assassins all week!