# How do I gain reputation as a new user and novice programmer?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to increase my reputation and privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146472/what-is-the-best-way-to-increase-my-reputation-and-privileges)

I am new to Stack Overflow, and I'm currently learning Objective-C with the [Big-nerd-ranch guide](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321706285). I have visited Stack Overflow repeatedly while learning [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) with [Zed-A-Shaw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zed_Shaw)'s [Learn python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/). I have to say, I couldn't have done it without the help of Stack Overflow.

I decided today that I'd come here and try to help other beginners with problems I had encountered myself and hopefully become a valid member of the community. I stumbled upon the chat rooms, specifically the iOS beginners room, which I found has a 20 reputation requirement to use. As a new user/programmer with limited knowledge, what sort of things can I actively do in the community that would help me gain this reputation? I do not want it for free of course, I just want tips of what someone like myself can do to help.

TL;DR: I'm a new user with limited knowledge of Python 2.7 and Objective-C, what can I do currently to help other users and gain the reputation required to use the beginners chat room?

Comment: If this question belongs anywhere it should be on meta, but is probably a duplicate even there, if not something you should read in the FAQ.

Comment: Well - all you need is two upvotes - answer a couple of Python/Objective-C questions, and it's not that difficult to get 20 rep (but there's lots of ways of gaining rep. as per @Ben's link)

Comment: I disagree that this is a duplicate question, in the one suggested, he is experienced and cannot find fresh, new questions to answer, My question was asking what I can do to help people out and earn my reputation when I have limited knowledge, his dilemma may well also apply to me, but it's not the same question and the same response will not answer them both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gain reputation by:

1. asking smart questions and accepting the answers,
2. answering questions in a good way,

All in all, be a valuable member and the reputation will come your way.

More can be found here in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).