# Illustrate or elaborate others questions via comments

Tags: discussion, comments

Is there a way to comment on/elaborate others question if I'm facing the same problem?
I do not have an answer or I do not want to create a duplicate question.

Answer (score 8):

### What you shouldn't do:

- post a duplicate question
- post an "I'm having the same issue" answer

### What you should/can do:

- request further clarification using comments. (requires [commenting privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment))
- place a bounty on the question, asking for more details (requires [bounty privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties))
- if you have a related question (not a duplicate one), you can also post a new question, citing the first one and clearly explaining how your question is related but different.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is duplicate, do not ask another question and don't ask for clarification by answering on that question. You need to earn [commenting privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to ask any question via comment. This privilege can be earned when you reach to 50 reputation.

Have a look at [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146472/187824) for best way to increase your reputation and privileges.

Comment: Worth noting that asking new questions in comments isn't a good idea.

Comment: @Emracool - Yeah if we want some clarification of a question or an answer then we can use comment. If we have a different question, it's worth to ask a separate question (after searching for a dup).