# How do I start getting reputation?

Tags: discussion, questions

I have tried commenting on a post on apple.stackexchange.com, but it said I needed 50 reputation. I then wanted to upvote the post instead since I don't have 50 reputation, but that was another 15 reputation.

So my question is if it takes 50 reputation to write a comment and 15 reputation to like something, how do I even start getting reputation?

Please help and if this is a stupid question can someone please point me in the right direction. I thought this meta page would be the best place to ask this; please do not roast me.

Comment: May be duplicate of [What is the best way to increase my reputation and privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146472/)

Answer (score 3):

You can gain reputation on Stack Exchange sites simply by answering questions. If the question you answer is good, people will upvote it, gaining 10 reputation per upvote. If your answer is selected as the accepted answer, you would gain an additional 15 reputation.

[A list of ways to gain reputation is listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), and a [list of privileges given based on reputation is listed here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: suggesting edits is more easy if not familiar with the technologies covered in that site

Comment: Yes, that is another very good point. Even if you don't know the answer to a question you can gain reputation even by just formatting the code in a question or answer.

Comment: One can also gain enough rep in one of the sites and then automatically the entire network gives +100 starting rep. For example that means one can be a 3D-printing expert to vote stuff up in EE.