# Is it bad style to reply quickly to give the first answer then edit the answer to make it better?

Tags: discussion, answers, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)

I've noticed some users who reply really quickly and then make a ton of edits to their original answer.
EDIT: is there anything that should be done in this situation, for example does this behavior warrant a down vote?

Comment: Maybe they read [6 simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/6-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast): _"Be the First to Answer. Even at the cost of quality."_  Disgusting... but improving upon a good submission is beneficial, I think.

Comment: Often I'll type out the entire post, but then edit it to have references to methods link to docs. The text doesn't change at all, it just becomes more useful, and finding the correct link can be time cumbersome and consuming.

Comment: What is the problem? That we get a fast answer, or that it is improved later? Both parts sounds good to me.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is very bad style.  It even has its own name - [Fastest Gun in the West.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/175248)

Answers should be complete by the time you're ready to reply to them.  If they're not, then who are you really helping?

Comment: Not to be contrary, but Jon Skeet is an advocate of this technique, and is quite good at it, I might add.

Comment: There's a big difference between posting a good answer quickly and returning to make it great, which is cool; and posting something that's only marginally more useful than "qwertyuiop" as a placeholder just to claim first place, which is not cool. Simply posting fast is not a problem.

Comment: The "qwertyuiop" posts are easily downvoted.