# Tapping to show "x more comments" loads comments from other answers, too

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, android-app

Trying to load  the rest of an answer's comments often loads comments from other answers, as well. That is, it loads all of its own comments properly, and then adds a bunch of comments from other answers onto the end. This is not happening on *every* answer that I can see, but I've been able to reproduce it every time one [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17205/168660) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17236/168660), as well as on others.

Pulling to refresh the answers list fixes this, leaving the comments expanded, but the extra ones removed.

Buggy one:
[image]

Comments are from here:
[image]

Comment: I was unable to reproduce using the examples provided with app version 0.1.33 on my Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.2.1. Which version of the app were you running?

Comment: Also 0.1.33 but on 4.3. I tried clicking the links to reproduce it again, but I was also unable to. So I went back to the main questions list and navigated manually from there, and I was able to reproduce it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in 0.1.37. The comments list can contain several invisible comments that are never removed when a view is recycled, and the "X more" button was un-hiding *all* of them, not just the ones that really belong on the particular post. The reason this didn't happen when following the direct link in your question is that in that case, we jump directly to the answer, so the comments view is used for the first time and has no chance to amass comments from other answers. When you navigate to the question and scroll through the answers,  the comments view picks up the comments from the answers above Shog9's.

From 0.1.37 we make sure to only un-hide comments that are really supposed to be visibile.