# How to get reputation on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

I think stackoverflow.com is great, and I would like to contribute. Usually, I find the answers to my questions are already there. I'd like to upvote the best answers and questions, but I do not have any reputation here. How do I get initial reputation?

The canonical way seems to ask a question. Which I hereby did.

Any other suggestions? I'd like to avoid stupid, pointless things (which I already failed to do by asking this question...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### How to gain reputation points

- Question is voted up: +5
- Answer is voted up: +10
- Your answer is marked as "accepted”: +15
- You mark an answer that isn't yours as "accepted": +2
- Suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
- Bounty awarded to your answer: +full bounty amount
- One of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: +1/2 of the bounty amount (see more details about how bounties work)
- Site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

#### You lose reputation points when:

- Your question is voted down: −2
- Your answer is voted down: −2
- You vote down an answer: −1
- You place a bounty on a question: −full bounty amount
- One of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags:−100

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Ah thanks for the honest answers.  A good summary of the system.  Asking the question, even though it was a duplicate one, seemed to have helped my reputation somehow. I have 9 points now, better than nothing (unless I started at 10)!?  Unfortunately, my question got downvoted, which certainly did not help my reputation.

Comment: Great, 2 more points for accepting your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Answer questions, then get upvotes from them. This should also be meta.

See [Six simple tips to get reputation fast on any Stack Exchange site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: Comments won't get you any reputation.

Comment: `"then get upvotes from them"`

Comment: The "them" appear to be pointed on the comments. The whole comments part is irrelevant here anyway, what made you mention this?

Comment: The "them" was aimed at comments and answers (eg. buy graphics cards, monitors, motherboards, and sell them for a really high price). I was also under the impression that comment-upvotes got you rep. Fixed.