# How can I ask additional question to given answer without reputation

Tags: support, reputation, comments

Somebody already asked my question. The answer has a nice example. When I try, only part of it works. How can I ask further question? Comment needs reputation. I'm new.

Comment: You could perhaps form the problems you're encountering into a question of your own, if you formulate it well.

Comment: Could you link the question that yours would be a duplicate of

Answer (score 7):

#### If the other question appears fully answered but does not answer your question

If the existing question appears fully answered but does not answer yours then your question is subtly different. You should establish what it is that separates your question from the previous question and establish your question around that.

#### If the other question is not answered fully and has not answered the original OPs problem

If the existing question does not appear to be fully answered I would normally suggest offering a bounty to draw attention to it, however you do not yet have the reputation for that. If the question remains unclear you could edit it to improve it. Failing that I'm afraid you'll have to wait till you've earned the 50 rep necessary to post your comment

Answer (score 4):

Feel free to ask another question, **but be sure to emphasize what you've tried, and why it doesn't work like you're trying to make it work**.

As long as you've put in the research effort and attempted solutions, and so long as it isn't fully encompassed by another question that's already been asked, it should be a perfectly acceptable question.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a fine opportunity to earn some reputation!

Ask a new question. Add a link to the question that was already asked, and point out where the answer was insufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Earn 50 reputation points. It's really not hard as it might sound, if you have fair programming skills.

You have many tips here on Meta how to gain reputation fast, most of them can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/152859).

In my opinion after couple of hours, one day at max, you'll get 50 rep and can then comment anywhere.

Comment: It is not hard to earn the reputation, but I disagree in this case, I'd let the OP ask an own question where he shows that he tried the other solution. He will usually earn some rep from that.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn but there is also risk of closure and downvotes if people will think it's duplicate.