# What exactly is retagging?

Tags: discussion, tags

What is retagging? I have an idea but not quite sure:

- When to retag?
- What needs retagging?
- What is manual retagging?
- Who can or cannot retag?

I tried to search for the answer, but interestingly enough, I could not locate an answer to this, I guess, very simple question.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging ? Or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq+tags ?

Comment: Thanks @Mat - never thought about checking help on meta :(

Comment: That help page is available on all sites. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/help/search?q=tags, the help center has a search feature

Comment: Yikes - sorry! I owe you donuts mate :)

Comment: I'd rather have pancakes. (_Without_ [the bunny](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17363/158667), always drops the damn things.) (-:

Comment: Hahaha, I will take the bunny, you take pancakes - too cute to let go! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Retagging in the broadest sense is changing a specific tag from one to another, i.e. changing [node](/questions/tagged/node) to [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).

Retagging occurs every time someone changes the tags on a post - but it is more commonly used to mean a *mass* retagging. This occurs when a tag is not used properly and the community needs to clean it up.

There is another process, tag synonymization, which also retags future posts from one to a new tag. This is slightly different, though, as it is an automatic process.

Retagging takes edit privileges, and is accessible through the edit button (just change the tags). However, 10K+ users have a dedicated "edit tags" button.