# How can I improve My reputation on Stack overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, reputation

I am new on this website. I have thirteen reputations on this website. I wants to ask that, how can I improve my reputations ? Sometimes I want to vote up for any question but website don't let me do that. Sometimes I want to share photo and solution for someone answer it don't allow me to do that. I always post productive questions and also make useful answer. Is there any way or tip so that, I can improve my reputation and become useful member for others ?

Comment: make sacrifices to the alter of the mighty Jon Skeet!

Comment: @gnat he's not a lurker, the first dupe is much better suited IMO.

Comment: @ShadowWizard first dupe is a better fit, no argument from me here. I extended dupe-list with tips oriented on lurker-type users only because "main dupe" was already pointed to

Answer (score 0):

You can do any of these to gain reputation points:

1. Give good answers so that you will get +10 for each up vote.
2. Ask good Question, each up vote will give you +5.
3. Edit questions and Answers so that you will get +2 on each approved edits.

Comment: Answer a bounty questions.....

Comment: @Kedarnath: Bounty questions are too difficult to answer ;) If some one has caliber then no doubt he can earn +50 to +500 in just one shot.

Comment: Agree, but once you start difficult thing, it becomes easy sooner or later.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to understand [how reputation works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work). There you will find a complete list what you can do to get or lose reputation.

Also there has been a question with [six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast).