# Block user to vote other answers of the questions when has provided already an answer

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, voting

I want to know what do you think about the possibility to block up and downvoting of other answers at the same question where you has already provided an answer. This because there are so many users that downvote answers only because in competition with its own answer.

I think that the community should decide which is the best answer and not one of the answerers. I know that one downvote can't influence the entire community but many times the first vote can influence the OP (especially in questions with low page visits).

Comment: No, when another answer is wrong, I as other answerer *am in an excellent position to judge that answer*. I'll also *up* vote *correct* answers.

Comment: "there are so many users that downvote answers only because in competition with its own answer" - where exactly did you get this juicy statistic from?

Comment: I have asked this because many times I have read here in Meta users that write "downvote others answers" as suggestion to get more rep in SO. I think that this is an horrible suggestion. Many times this kind of answer has several +1

Comment: @Oded See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site

Comment: Related http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291131/prevent-voting-on-answers-by-users-who-have-answers

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just because I answer a question doesn't mean that I have automatically accounted for all possible answers to the question.

Someone else could have posted an alternative approach, which may be better (or worse) under some situations in comparison to mine.  If I think that approach is also valuable, then I'll upvote that answer.  There's even [a badge to encourage this behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/119/sportsmanship).

Someone else could have posted something terribly wrong.  In that case, I want to ensure future visitors to the question don't walk away with an incorrect answer, one that may even be potentially dangerous.  I downvote these answers.

Why should my voting be restricted just because I answered? As [Martijn says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237337/block-user-to-vote-other-answers-of-the-questions-when-has-provided-already-an-a#comment778023_237337), "I as other answerer am in an excellent position to judge that answer."

Comment: Thanks @Troyen, I agree completly with you. I have asked this because many times I read users that suggest other users to use downvote to get more probability to see its answer as accepted. I think that this is an horrible thing to write and to think because the spirit of this community should be different (fortunately I am speaking about a minority part of users)

Comment: @faby and where are you seeing those suggestions?

Comment: Here in meta post..  If i find it I'll post here

Comment: @Lamak See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site