# How to gain reputation on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I would love to comment on & participate in discussion on the various Stack Exchange sites, but I don't have enough reputation. The one I have the most reputation on (http://stackoverflow.com) has 46 rep points. Not enough to do anything productive. As a software engineer, I often Google to find out how to do something, and find the question has already been asked or answered on Stack Overflow, but just reading other people's questions and answers doesn't give me any reputation.

So what do I need to do to increase my reputation enough to prove I'm not a troll?

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site?rq=1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do one of three things:

1. **Ask questions.** Asking questions about something you don't know helps solve your problem and also helps anyone in the future who may have the same problem. If you've had a problem but have now found a solution, you can self-answer your question, which is both [allowed and even encouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-if-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking). You get +5 reputation points per question upvote.
2. **Answer questions.** As a software engineer, you obviously have some expertise. Why not share it? You might be able to find a niche topic or set of questions that you can answer better than anyone else. You get +10 reputation points per answer upvote.
3. **Edit questions.** For anyone who doesn't yet have editing privileges, each approved suggested edit gives you +2 reputation points. You can edit questions, answers, and tag wikis.

It sounds like you want comment privileges, which you get at 50 reputation points. All you have to do is get two edits approved, or ask one question with a positive score, or give one answer with a positive score.