# Minimum rep to edit an answer?

Tags: support, reputation, edits

Here on Meta, I was able to edit [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/287826), without it going to a review queue, even though I only have 268 rep here.  However, on Spanish SE Beta, I have 800 rep and my edits go to the review queue.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 9):

The answer you edited was Community Wiki.

[100 rep is enough to edit Community Wiki posts.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) It has nothing to do with here being meta.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site/17250#17250

Comment: You are correct, I hadn't noticed.  I edited: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17250/287826