# Voting on locked comments visual bug

Tags: bug

It seems the X button on locked comment voting lost's it's X

Grab any locked post, such as [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/259147) .

Scroll to the comments, and try to upvote any comment.
And tada, greeted with a big Ã—

[image]