# Some locked posts show voting buttons

Tags: bug, locked-questions

[This locked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/399694) has voting buttons:

[image: This post shows non-functional voting buttons]

However, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/17204/399694) does not:

[image: This post does not show voting buttons]

On questions that show them or don't, the same is true for their answers.

**Why is this? Shouldn't it never show them, because it's misleading and harder to distinguish that a post is locked?**

Comment: Only historically locked questions have ever been designed to hide the voting buttons. See [What is a historical lock, and what is it used for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for)

Comment: @animuson but why? Voting is disabled anyway - why not show that by hiding the voting buttons on locked posts too? Some locks are also permanent too (including the one linked in the question)

Comment: Wow all this time I've never known that there was such thing as "historical locking", I thought all locked questions were treated the same.

Comment: @animuson so status-by-design?