# How I can get more reputation to be able to vote in my questions?

Tags: discussion

I'm new in this type of sites but I want to be part of the community, I already make a question but I can't vote in it know. I will be very grateful if you can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I appreciate your good intentions and welcome you to the community. The entire network works based on the content you post, not on the user. If you post quality answers / questions you get reputation for that. Suggesting good substantial edits that get accepted also give reputation points.

No-one besides yourself helps you.

[See this old meta post how to increase your reputation quickly.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry for bother you all.